# Как выполняется проверка if через параметры?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть вот такой код самостоятельной реализации метода filter, но я совсем не понимаю как внутри if мы в параметр fn, передаем elem и выполняем проверку.

Каким образом fn(elem) понимает с чем сравнивать?

```js
const filterThis = [2, 4, 3, 6, 8, 9];

const filter = (arr, fn) => {
  const filteredArr = [];
  for (let elem of arr) {
    if (fn(elem)) filteredArr.push(elem);
  }
  return filteredArr;
}

console.log(filter(filterThis, (elem) => elem % 3 == 0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По факту получается так. С простого. Сама анонимная функция может быть записана так:

```
function test(elem) {
    if (elem % 3 == 0)
        return true;

    return false;    
}
```

внутри `filter` происходит вызов этой функции, переданной по ссылке и передаётся аргумент `elem`

В целом, если пока без ссылки, то получается вот так:

```
const filter = (arr) => {
    ...
    if (test(elem)) 
    ...        
}
```

если с ссылкой

```
const filter = (arr, ЛЮБАЯ_ФУНКЦИЯ) => {
    ...
    if (ЛЮБАЯ_ФУНКЦИЯ(elem)) 
    ...        
}

filter(filterThis, test);
```

Дальше, просто т.к. это стрелочная функция, считайте, что ей произвольно задаётся имя (не важно как), сохраняется в глобальном скоупе и передаётся оно как аргумент функции. Считайте, что в данном случае вот это

```
(elem) => elem % 3 == 0
```

сохранилось как `function test(elem)` и `test` передался как аргумент в `filter`